# Standardize or not standardize with R: pnorm function error?

Tags: r, probability, mean, standard-error, sample

This is question related to `R` and problem with sample means.

According to code below, I wonder why `pnorm` gives different result for `pnorm` with critical value **x*** with specified `mu` and `sd` parameters than when using `pnorm` with standardized critical value **z*** ?

```
# population parameters
mu = 29321
sigma = 2120

# sample size
n = 100L

xstar = 29000
zstar = (xstar-mu)/(sigma/sqrt(n))
p = pnorm(zstar) # should be around 0.0649
p = pnorm(xstar, mean=mu, sd=sigma) # why p = 0.4398????
```

Numbers taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQn8OIywoQ0

Comment: If you want to obtain same values.

Answer (score 2):

If you are standardising, you don't need to divide sigma by sqrt(n).

I know it's all a bit murky, but you have random variables $X$ which you believe follow a normal distribution $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.   If you want to standardise these variables, then $Z = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}$ has a standard Normal distribution $Z \sim N(0, 1)$.
Change the line to `zstar = (xstar-mu)/sigma` and I get 0.4398241.

The thing where you divide by $\sqrt{N}$ applies when we are talking about standard errors of the mean, this is all about a sampling distribution for $\bar{X}$ and NOT $X$.

One feature/bug of R is the way the `pnorm`/`rnorm` etc. are parameterised in terms of standard deviation and not variance. You've got that all correct, took me ages before I got that right automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
zstar = (xstar-mu)/(sigma)
p1 = pnorm(zstar) 
p2 = pnorm(xstar, mean=mu, sd=sigma)
```

You divide the standard deviation of the population when you want to obtain the standard deviation of the estimator.